# Uncaught TypeError on console

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, slider

could you please explain what mean the following error?

I'm not familiar with Js.
I

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sss is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (codejs.js:3)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ codejs.js:3
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
ready @ jquery.min.js:2
J @ jquery.min.js:2
```

This is my index.html

```
<script src="{% static 'js/sss/sss.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js'%}"></script>
<script src=" {% static 'js/codejs.js' %}"></script>
```

On my codejs.js I'm calling the slider sss

```
$(function($) {

  $('.slider').sss();

});
```

Thanks

Comment: Try swapping the order of your scripts so `sss` is after `jquery`. (sss is a jquery plugin, so jquery has to already exist when its code runs)

Comment: tnx sir! appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here js is showing error because their is no `sss()` function declared that is why its showing you uncaught. so you should include js  in sequence so that js first knows that this `sss()` function exits and then call it .

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js'%}"></script>
<script src=" {% static 'js/codejs.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/sss/sss.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: You should move the custom script (codejs.js) to the bottom.

Comment: i thought custom script is (sss.js) , i.e why i added it first

Comment: `sss.js` is Super Simple Slider, a jQuery plugin. `codejs.js` is OP's code I assume.